# RecyclerView smoothScrollToPosition scrolls to incorrect location when the activity layout has layout weight,or the CardView is within a Linear Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I'm getting unexpected behavior when I'm calling `recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition`.

When I add enough items and start going off the screen, it doesn't properly scroll to the bottom, staying 2-3 behind. Then, after adding 15 or so, it starts scrolling to position 0 when I add an item, and then the next item scrolls to the bottom.  Add another item and it goes to 0, and then again and it goes to the bottom.

You can see in the attached video what's happening. Pay attention to the scroll bar as well once it starts going off the screen.

Gif on imgur, but limited to 15 secs.  http://i.imgur.com/FnjsTY1.gifv]

The whole video is available here - https://www.dropbox.com/s/k6aaca5ue6lkk21/device-2016-05-27-130928.mp4?dl=0

I tore my app apart until I narrowed it down to two things that suddenly fix the problem in a test app.

My activity layout uses layout weights, and when I remove that, it begins to scroll properly again. Additionally my CardView that is shown in the recylerView has an extra LinearLayout around it.  Removing that also solves the problem.

**Neither of these solutions work in my app** as there's probably more "gotcha" problems just like these two. This is also me tearing it down to the minimum amount to show the bug, my layouts are much more complex.

I'm not sure what to do, since I'm not even entirely sure why it's wrong. I've tried custom linear layout managers with custom scrollers and it's always the same problem.

Below is the code used to re-create the problem

MainActivity

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).commit();
    }
}
```

MyFragment with the RecyclerView

```
public class MyFragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerAdapter adapter;
    ViewGroup rootView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentlayout, container, false);

        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.inventory_recycler);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
        adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(new ArrayList<RecyclerItem>());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        Button button = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addItem();
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    public void addItem(){
        adapter.getList().add(new RecyclerItem());
        adapter.notifyItemAdded(adapter.getList().size()-1);
        recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(adapter.getList().size()-1);
    }

    public class RecyclerItem {
        public RecyclerItem(){
        }
    }

    public static class RecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView name;
        public RecyclerViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
        }
    }

    public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewHolder> {

        private final List<RecyclerItem> items;

        public RecyclerAdapter(List<RecyclerItem> items) {
            this.items = items;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return items.size();
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
            viewHolder.name.setText("" + position);
        }

        public List<RecyclerItem> getList() {
            return items;
        }

        public void notifyItemAdded(int position) {
            notifyItemInserted(position);
        }

        @Override
        public RecyclerViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.
                    from(viewGroup.getContext()).
                    inflate(R.layout.card, viewGroup, false);

            return new RecyclerViewHolder(itemView);
        }
    }
}
```

Activity Layout **(Removing the layout weight and setting value solves problem)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

      <FrameLayout
          android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Fragment Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="add item" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/inventory_recycler"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/button"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Card Layout **(Removing the extra LinearLayout solves the problem)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        app:elevation="3dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sample.recyclertest"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
}
```

Comment: Additional Info - Smooth scrolling to the position works if it's already in the list.  Adding a delayed post to smooth scroll to a newly added item does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One straight forward solution to do this is using recyclerview-v7:23.1.1 instead of recyclerview-v7:23.4.0.

Another solution is using this method

```
/**
     * RecyclerView can perform several optimizations if it can know in advance that RecyclerView's
     * size is not affected by the adapter contents. RecyclerView can still change its size based
     * on other factors (e.g. its parent's size) but this size calculation cannot depend on the
     * size of its children or contents of its adapter (except the number of items in the adapter).
     * <p>
     * If your use of RecyclerView falls into this category, set this to {@code true}. It will allow
     * RecyclerView to avoid invalidating the whole layout when its adapter contents change.
     *
     * @param hasFixedSize true if adapter changes cannot affect the size of the RecyclerView.
     */
    public void setHasFixedSize(boolean hasFixedSize)
```

`recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);` should solve your problem. for 23.4.0

The problem with your code was, whenever you were calling notifyItemInserted(), the entire recyclerview was getting drawn again which was moving your recyclerview to go to the first position. On top of that you were calling `recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(adapter.getList().size() - 1);` which means the view was going to top as well as scrolling to the last position at the same time. That's why it was not going to the bottom most position. so just call `recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);` to prevent it from redrawing.

Comment: The first suggestion you have to downgrade does resolve the issue.  I also logged a bug report with google and they pointed me to this https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=203276 which further explains the problem.  I also had to revert the design library as well though to stop the problem, not just the recyclerview one.   The whole second part of the answer though doesn't make sense.  I was correctly setting the last position every time, and setHasFixedSized does not resolve anything.  I'm giving the bounty to you since in my case the downgrade worked, but there's no rationale.

Comment: The second option does makes sense. See there is no issue with recyclerview. The only thing is whenever you do `adapter.notifyItemInserted()`, changes happen and the recyclerview moves to the very first position. You can verify this by removing the call to smoothScrollToPosition(); Now using recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true); will prevent recyclerview from going back to the very first position which will solve your problem. I don't know why it din't work for you but I put that in the code provided by you and it worked for me without downgrading the library to 23.1.1.